# Sublime Text build batch file

Tags: batch-file, sublimetext2

When I press `Ctrl + Shift + B` in Sublime Text, I have a batch file running, inside this batch file I have the following:

```
set arg1=%1
echo %arg1%
set arg2=%arg1:c:=r:%
echo %arg2%
set arg3=%arg1:c:=z:%
echo %arg3%
bcompare %arg1% %arg2% 
bcompare %arg1% %arg3%
```

So, I get the file path on `C:\` and compare the file (using Beyond Compare 3) with exact same path except on `R:\`. This has been working great, but today I had to make some changes to my file and folder structures on `C:\` and the path to say `mytestfile.php` is now:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Main\site\mytestfile.php

So the bit that has changed is the `Main\` HOWEVER on drive `R:\` I don't have that Main folder, and I want the path to be:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\mytestfile.php

How can I change the code in the `.bat` file to account for this change by removing the `Main\` for the file path on `R:\` and `Z:\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you did the others substitutions :

```
set $path=%1
set $path1=%$path:main\=%

echo %$path%
set $path2=%$path1:c:=r:%
echo %$path2%
set $path3=%$path1:c:=z:%
echo %$path3%
echo bcompare %$path% %$path2% 
echo bcompare %$path% %$path3%
```

Comment: This does not work! it has removed the `Main` from the file path on `C:` as well! I only want to remove it on the other two drives :(

Comment: though it helped me get to the answer. Thanks

Comment: Check the EDIT now is OK

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `arg2`variable to not include the main directory.

```
set arg1=%1
echo %arg1%
set arg2=%arg1:c:=r:%
echo %arg2%
set arg3=%arg1:c:=z:%
echo %arg3%

::Select which parts of the path you want from %%a (drive letter) to the file
for /f "tokens=1* delims=\" %%a in ("%arg1:"=%") do (set arg2="%%a\%%b\%%c\%%e")

::  Compare
::  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Main\site\mytestfile.php
::  %%a\%%b    \%%c   \%%d  \%%e \%%f

bcompare %arg1% %arg2% 
bcompare %arg1% %arg3%
```